# Is it possible to plot a series of matrices in this format using gnuplot

Tags: arrays, matrix, gnuplot, heatmap, animated-gif

My code currently creates an output that comes out as so (using example numbers)

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 2.0 

0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 2.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 0.0 


0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 3.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 1.0 


3.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 2.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 


3.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 2.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 


3.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 2.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 


3.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 2.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0
```

was hoping for a solution on how to plot this data either as a 3D splot or as a gif that cycles through each matrix (actual code contains a few hundred matrices). I'm able to alter the output format if necessary. So far I've tried

```
do for [i=1:7] {
plot "data.txt" matrix with image
}
```

As well as attempting other solutions I've found on the site but none seem to be trying to do the same thing as me.

If anyone who has gnuplot experience could help me that would be a huge help (I'm using mac if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 1):

I assume all separations of your matrices are **two** empty lines.
If this is the case you can address the matrices via `index` (check `help index`).
You can find out with `stats` (check `help stats`) how many blocks you have. Loop through these blocks and set the output to `term gif animate` (check `help gif`). Instead of plotting the datablock `$Data` simply plot your file.

**Scrupt:**

```
### plot matrices as asnimation
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 2.0 


0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 2.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 0.0 


0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 3.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 1.0 


3.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 2.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 


3.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 2.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 


3.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 2.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
EOD


stats $Data u 0 nooutput    # get the number of blocks
N = STATS_blocks

set term gif size 600,400 animate delay 30
set output "SO72250259.gif"

set size ratio -1
set cbrange [0:3]
set xrange [-0.5:2.5]
set yrange [-0.5:3.5]

do for [i=0:N-1] {
    plot $Data index i matrix w image
}
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: hey any chance you also know how to do this for a 2d plot
with 2 line breaks like before

Comment: @maxmars yes, that's the same principle, e.g. `plot $Data u 1:2 index i w lines` within a for loop. It depends on the data structure and which columns you actually want to plot.

Comment: hey sorry to keep asking, I've received the data i need to do it to and I'm struggling to create the right boundaries. it is a 10x10 matrix with values like 9.062121347690136e-34 and 5.181881622252534e-08 and 0.01831563888873418. Is it possible to have this method still work with enough precision that the result will create something that looks good? I can send the entire text file if that's useful, I'm just struggling to create the correct cbrange and x/y range. Thanks so much if you could help

Comment: @maxmars That's why is is good to have a minimal example with _real_ data. Values from 9e-34 to 1e-2 and you want to "see" them all over 32 orders of magnitude? Then try to use `set logscale cb`, but even then it will probably difficult. If it is just one 10x10 matrix you can edit your question and add the data formatted as code.

Comment: @maxmars Problem solved? Please provide the real data if you are interested in a reasonable solution.